# Интроспекция объекта - как узнать структуру некоторого объекта?

Tags: python, python-2.x, swig

Есть некоторое API, вызов функции возвращает объект.
Объект обладает неизвестной мне структурой.

Гугл подсказывает, что есть множество способов интроспекции.
Есть ли стандартный способ, позволяющий отобразить структуру объекта?
Конкретно меня волнуют  поля объекта - их типы и имена.

Использовал `__dict__`, результат:

```
{'this': <Swig Object of type 'table_ptr_t *' at 0x0000000002724210>}
```

Если объект сгенерирован SWIG могу ли я получить, структуру объекта?

Comment: Фунция [dir](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir), например.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

```
import inspect, sys
filter_is = [a for a in dir(inspect) if a.startswith('is')]

class B:
    Z = range(4)
    def attr(self, a: [Z, Z.__class__.__name__], z, *args, x=Z, y='y5', **kwargs): pass

class A(B):
    def __init__(self):
        self.Y = 1, 2, 3
    @classmethod
    def attr2(cls: object) -> str: pass
    @staticmethod
    def attr1(): pass

c = A()
a = c.__class__

print(inspect.classify_class_attrs(a))
print(inspect.getclasstree(inspect.getmro(a)))

print(inspect.getmembers(с))

for an in dir(c):
    if not an.startswith('_'):
        ga = getattr(c, an)

        print('-' * 20)
        print(dict(name=an,
                   type=type(ga),
                   id=id(ga),
                   len=len(ga) if hasattr(ga, '__len__') else None,
                   getsizeof=sys.getsizeof(ga),
                   getrefcount=sys.getrefcount(ga)))

        print({k: getattr(inspect, k)(ga) for k in filter_is})
        print(ga)
        if callable(ga):
            print(inspect.getsource(ga))
            print(inspect.getfullargspec(ga))
            print(inspect.formatargspec(*inspect.getfullargspec(ga)))
```

out:

```
Attribute(name='Z', kind='data', defining_class=<class '__main__.B'>, object=range(0, 4)), Attribute(name='__class__', kind='data', defining_class=...
[(<class 'object'>, ()), [(<class '__main__.B'>, (<class 'object'>,)), [(<class '__main__.A'>, (<class '__main__.B'>,))]]]
[('Y', (1, 2, 3)), ('Z', range(0, 4)), ('__class__', <class '__main__.A'>), ('__delattr__', <method-wrapper '__delattr__' of A object at 0x029C94B0>), ('__dict__', {'Y': (1, 2, 3)}),.....
--------------------
{'type': <class 'tuple'>, 'name': 'Y', 'len': 3, 'getsizeof': 40, 'id': 9584592, 'getrefcount': 4}
{'isclass': False, 'ismethod': False, 'istraceback': False, 'isabstract': False, 'ismethoddescriptor': False, 'isfunction': False, 'isgenerator': False, 'ismodule': False, 'isroutine': False, 'isdatadescriptor': False, 'iscode': False, 'isframe': False, 'isgetsetdescriptor': False, 'isgeneratorfunction': False, 'isbuiltin': False, 'ismemberdescriptor': False}
(1, 2, 3)
--------------------
{'type': <class 'range'>, 'name': 'Z', 'len': 4, 'getsizeof': 24, 'id': 9225184, 'getrefcount': 5}
{'isclass': False, 'ismethod': False, 'istraceback': False, 'isabstract': False, 'ismethoddescriptor': False, 'isfunction': False, 'isgenerator': False, 'ismodule': False, 'isroutine': False, 'isdatadescriptor': False, 'iscode': False, 'isframe': False, 'isgetsetdescriptor': False, 'isgeneratorfunction': False, 'isbuiltin': False, 'ismemberdescriptor': False}
range(0, 4)
--------------------
{'type': <class 'method'>, 'name': 'attr', 'len': None, 'getsizeof': 36, 'id': 9017304, 'getrefcount': 2}
{'isclass': False, 'ismethod': True, 'istraceback': False, 'isabstract': False, 'ismethoddescriptor': False, 'isfunction': False, 'isgenerator': False, 'ismodule': False, 'isroutine': True, 'isdatadescriptor': False, 'iscode': False, 'isframe': False, 'isgetsetdescriptor': False, 'isgeneratorfunction': False, 'isbuiltin': False, 'ismemberdescriptor': False}
<bound method A.attr of <__main__.A object at 0x009394B0>>
    def attr(self, a: [Z, Z.__class__.__name__], z, *args, x=Z, y='y5', **kwargs): pass

FullArgSpec(args=['self', 'a', 'z'], varargs='args', varkw='kwargs', defaults=None, kwonlyargs=['x', 'y'], kwonlydefaults={'y': 'y5', 'x': range(0, 4)}, annotations={'a': [range(0, 4), 'range']})
(self, a: [range(0, 4), 'range'], z, *args, x=range(0, 4), y='y5', **kwargs)
--------------------
{'type': <class 'function'>, 'name': 'attr1', 'len': None, 'getsizeof': 72, 'id': 33140928, 'getrefcount': 3}
{'isclass': False, 'ismethod': False, 'istraceback': False, 'isabstract': False, 'ismethoddescriptor': False, 'isfunction': True, 'isgenerator': False, 'ismodule': False, 'isroutine': True, 'isdatadescriptor': False, 'iscode': False, 'isframe': False, 'isgetsetdescriptor': False, 'isgeneratorfunction': False, 'isbuiltin': False, 'ismemberdescriptor': False}
<function A.attr1 at 0x01F9B0C0>
    @staticmethod
    def attr1(): pass

FullArgSpec(args=[], varargs=None, varkw=None, defaults=None, kwonlyargs=[], kwonlydefaults=None, annotations={})
()
--------------------
{'type': <class 'method'>, 'name': 'attr2', 'len': None, 'getsizeof': 36, 'id': 9017304, 'getrefcount': 2}
{'isclass': False, 'ismethod': True, 'istraceback': False, 'isabstract': False, 'ismethoddescriptor': False, 'isfunction': False, 'isgenerator': False, 'ismodule': False, 'isroutine': True, 'isdatadescriptor': False, 'iscode': False, 'isframe': False, 'isgetsetdescriptor': False, 'isgeneratorfunction': False, 'isbuiltin': False, 'ismemberdescriptor': False}
<bound method type.attr2 of <class '__main__.A'>>
    @classmethod
    def attr2(cls: object) -> str: pass

FullArgSpec(args=['cls'], varargs=None, varkw=None, defaults=None, kwonlyargs=[], kwonlydefaults=None, annotations={'cls': <class 'object'>, 'return': <class 'str'>})
(cls: object) -> str
```

Comment: def attr1(self, **x: int**): - Python так умеет?

Comment: нет, это анотация, проверка типа не происходит

Comment: @veryStupidJunior, проверку типов можно делать сторонними средствами, в составе IDE (например, PyCharm) или отдельно ([mypy](https://github.com/python/mypy)).

Comment: Есть ли альтернатива для **getfullargspec()** в python 2.?

Comment: inspect.getargspec()

Answer (score 0):

Конкретно, про встроенный в стандартную библиотеку python способ интроинспекции объектов я не слышал, вряд ли он есть.

---

Тем не менее можно ведь использовать инструменты для отладки:

**Во первых** есть стандартный [отладчик](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html).

**Во вторых**, отладчик среды разработки [pycharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) прекрасно и наглядно отображает структуру любого объекта, с типами, содержимым и всем остальным что нам как пользователям совсем не надо. Очень рекомендую. Снимет много лишней нагрузки, как с разработчика.

**В третьих**, написать свой инспектор объекта совсем несложно. Не думаю, что это займёт больше десятка строк. Хотя так отлаживать, конечно, не будет удобным.

Ну и **в четвёртых**, есть отладчик в IDLE, там как для новичков отображается только нужное. Атрибуты необходимых объектов, прямо во время выполнения программы, посмотреть труда не составит.

> Если объект сгенерирован SWIG могу ли я получить, структуру объекта?

Не пробовал, но по идее если объект, уже находится в зоне видимости python то проблем быть не должно.